# How to take picture on Android (API Level 21)?

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm new to Android development but have Java/C# experience. I want to use camera api to take a picture, show on the screen and save to disk.

I like to use newest api, which says android.hardware.Camera is obsolete and we should use android.hardware.camera2. I searched the Internet but found few information on android.hardware.camera2.

Here is what I have now.

```
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    String[] ids = manager.getCameraIdList();
    for (String id : ids) {
        CameraCharacteristics ch = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(id);
        if (ch.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_BACK) {
            manager.openCamera(id, new CameraCallback(), null);
        }
    }
```

.

```
class CameraCallback extends CameraDevice.StateCallback {

    @Override
    public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
        try {
            CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = camera.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);

        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {        }

    @Override
    public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {        }
}
```

I have no idea after `CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder` what I should do. I want to see some samples.

Besides, what control should I use to display the image?

Comment: Please follow the link. It may solve your query.
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic.